# Pixel and omxplayer - menu bar shines through

Tags: omxplayer, pixel

There is a weird thing with the latest Raspbian with Pixel (*): even when using `-b` to black out the background, playing back a video with omxplayer, I can see very faint the desktop manager's menu bar shining through (the wifi icon and the bottom line of the bar are offset against the video; I have a matte gray video and those icons are off by a few gray steps; I tried rotating the video to make sure the problem is not in the source, the fine line stays on the top).

Is there a trick/workaround to hide the Pixel menu bar?

(*) perhaps this was also with older versions, I'm just seeing it now.